# Check parent mounting status when updating state from a child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-component, react-state

In my react native 0.59.9 app, the `App` class has 2 states which may be updated by child components.

```
class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    group_id: this.props.navigation.state.params.data.group_id,
    result: this.props.navigation.state.params.data.result,  
  };

 updateGroup = (group_id) => {
    console.log("In updateGroup : ", group_id);
    this.setState({group_id:group_id});
  };

  updateToken = (token) => {
    console.log("In updateToken : ", token);
    this.setState({result: token});
  };

const EventWithSelf = (props) => (<Event {...props} updateToken={this.updateToken}  />)
const GroupWithSelf = (props) => (<Group {...props} updateGroup={this.updateGroup} updateToken={this.updateToken} />);   
..........
}
```

`Event` and `Group` are child components which may update the `App`'s state. 
In both `updateGroup` and `updateToken`, how does the app checkomg the mounting state of the `App` before executing `setState`? My concern is that the `App` may not be mounted when `setState` is executed. This will certainly throw out warnings.

UPDATE:

The `updateToken` is in `componentDidMount` in both `Event` and `Group`. updateGroup is triggged by click. Here is the code:

```
async _onPress(id) {
      let element = this.state.activeGroups;
      let element1 = element.find((e) => {
        console.log("e is ", e);
        return (e.id == id);
      });
      //save group_id clicked
      try {
        console.log("saved group id in Group : ", element1.id);
        await helper.setMyValue("group_id", element1.id.toString());
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("error in saving group_id to local disk", err);
      };
      this.props.updateGroup(element1.id); //<<<=== this causes "warning of no-op with updating unmounted component" in `Event` component.
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Event", {group_id:element1.id});
      return;
    }
```

Comment: see [`componentDidMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

Comment: It depends on at what time you are calling the updateGroup and updateToken method. Can you share event and group component code.

Comment: `Amardeep Singh`, updated. the `updateToken` is in componentDidMount in both `Event` and `Group`. updateGroup is triggged by click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `componentDidMount` lifecycle method to set a `flag`, and then pass this flag to the child components.

Define the flag `isMounted`:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isMounted: false,
        };
    }
```

Set `isMounted` to `true` when component mounts.

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.setState=({ isMounted: true })
}
```

And pass it down to the children.

```
<Event {...props} isMounted={this.state.isMounted} updateToken={this.updateToken}  />
```

Then, you can use `isMounted` flag to check the mounting status of the `App` before executing `setState` in the child components.

Comment: Is there a way the app can guarantee the execution of `updateToken` and `updateGroup`? It is really important to get both `result` and `group_id` updated in `App.js` whenever there is change to it.

Comment: @user938363 As long as your component is mounted, you can update its state. You can use `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method to set `isMounted` flag to `false`. `componentWillUnmount` is called just before component is unmounted.

Comment: Added _isMounted as a class variable and check it before `setState`.